# Remove ResultSet cached data

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I need the query ResultSet size and I do that with the follow code:

```
int size =0;
if (rs != null) {
rs.last();
size = rs.getRow();
rs.beforeFirst();
}
```

Than I iterate the ResultSet with the classic:

```
while (rs.next()) {
// do some
}
```

Now, if I have for example 200 row inside my ResultSet the execution time of iteration is about 500 milliseconds. If I execute the first part of code (to get the ResultSet size) the iteration execution time goes down to 50 milliseconds.

this probably happens because the data is cached, is there a way to avoid this or to clean the cache?

Thank you

---

Hi guys and thanks for replies, so:

1. I need to know how many rows are in the result set because of some queries extract thousand of records and I need to inform user about the percentage of progress. To do this I clearly need the maximum value and the intermediate values.
2. As Bob Jarvis says, I want to re-iterate the result set as slow as first, it is pretty stupid but I can't push message to the client at intervals lower than 100 milliseconds and if I get the ResultSet as written above (first part of code) the progress information are rather useless.
   For example: a resultset which contains 600 rows takes 500 millisecond to do this:

   int size =0;
   if (rs != null) {
   rs.last();
   size = rs.getRow();
   rs.beforeFirst();
   }

and 60 to iterate it again as follow:

```
while (rs.next()) {
// do some
}
```

Than maybe I can waste some seconds to iterate the resultSet slower but give more accurate information to the user about the execution time of some elaboration.

Thank you all.

Comment: why do you want to clear the cache?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the re-query to be as slow as the first, or that you want the first query to be as fast as the second?

Comment: Why do you need to know how many rows there are in the result set?